# C++ SDL2 how to color individual tiles

Tags: c++, colors, sdl-2, tile

I'm learning C++ and SDL2 by programming a classic **roguelike**. Right now I build the map by rendering part of a `tiles.png` image like this one:

[image: tiles]

I followed [lazyfoo's tiling tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/39_tiling/index.php) and it works, but I would like to be able to change each tile background and foreground colors. I can change the full texture colors doing something like [this other tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/40_texture_manipulation/index.php), but what if I want, say, a brown door somewhere and a gray one somewhere else?

What's the best approach here? Obviously I can't have hundreds of color combinations stored in pngs. Should I create a texture for each tile, or there is a better way?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDL-2 means that you use opengl to render tiles. Use blending and color materials. Use `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor`, `SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode`, `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode` `SDL_SetTextureColorMod`, `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod`.
For example to draw yellow letters:

```
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(renderer, 255, 255, 0);
```

to draw different background you need to use letters with alpha-channel. First you need to draw background where text appears, then draw text itself.
For example:

```
//load surface with alpha-channel here
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 255); //set blue background
//draw rect for background here
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(renderer, 255, 255, 0); //set yellow letters
SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
//draw text here
```

Or cheeting version (if you dont want to use alpha-blending):

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 255); //set blue background
//draw rect for background here
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(renderer, 255, 255, 0); //set yellow letters
SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_ADD);
//draw text here
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But wouldn't `SDL_SetTextureColorMod` affect the whole texture?

Comment: Yes. Whole texture become yellow. Actually not texture but the modulating color. If you want the tagged text (colored) you need to write your own text renderer that define what color of text you need (maybe through analizing the tags) and switch texture color with sdl_settexturecolormod. Text is just the sequance of colored rectangles with different texture coords.

Comment: Ok, it worked. First I use `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` to set the tile background, then I use `SDL_RenderFillRect`. With `SDL_SetTextureColorMod` I set the foreground color and finally with `SDL_RenderCopy` and `SDL_RenderPresent` I render everything.